# Как поставить begintransaction в очередь?

Tags: php, laravel, transaction

Как поставить begintransaction в очередь?
Ребят, приветствую.
Вопрос по транзакциям:
Есть скрипт, который изменяет ячейку. Но дело в том, что если я например делаю одновременный запрос с двух устройств, то один запрос(который первее) выполняется, а второй нет. А нужно чтобы выполнялись оба, только в порядке очереди.
Как правильно реализовывать подобное. Не нашел информации по этому вопросу, а может просто не правильно задал вопрос.

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$balanceNow = Users::find(Auth::id());

if ($balanceNow < $request->sum) {
  return Response::json([
     "errors" => ["Ошибка"]
  ], 422);
}

$response = json_decode(Wallet::send($request->address, $request->sum));
//записи в базе
if ($response->desc == 'OK') {
   DB::commit();
}else{
   DB::rollBack();
}
```

Заранее премного благодарен за наводку в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Begintransaction не нужно ставить в очередь. Транзакции ставятся в очередь автоматически, и ждут завершения предыдущей.

Comment: Странно, тогда почему не выполняются два одновременных запроса? Причина в другом?